# auto-vectorization of "is any of these characters in string"

Tags: c++, clang, vectorization, simd, auto-vectorization

checking if a characters are in a string should be fairly simple to speed up using simd. I was hoping modern auto-vectorization would give me portability + speed, but i can't figure out how to give the compiler enough hints to do it.

here's what i tried:

```
static char find1[] = {
    '"','"','"','"','"','"','"','"',
    '\\','\\','\\','\\', '\\','\\','\\','\\'
};
int match8(char *tpl)
{ 
    int r = 0;
    for (int  at = 0; at < 8; at++) { 
        r |= (tpl[at] == find1[at]);
    }
    for (int  at = 0; at < 8; at++) { 
        r |= (tpl[at] == find1[at + 8]);
    } 
    return r;
}
```

according to godbolt

https://godbolt.org/z/7ao1rG

clang does emit some nice simd, but gcc unrolls the loop instead.

is this an inherit limit of gcc, or can i change my code to make it emit simd instead?

Comment: I couldn't make it happen automatically either. Is doing it manually an option?

Comment: @harold as a last resort, yes. At the very least, i could hope to remove it later when compilers get better.

Comment: The clang output looks pretty descent -- even better if you add a `-march=XYZ` which supports AVX2 (it will then use a `vpbroadcast`). It does indeed not inline very well, but you should probably rather care about some real use-case (e.g., do you require this test in a hot-loop?)

Comment: @chtz you are correct. -march=native is as good as it gets in clang. i did try writing it manually now and couldnt come up with anything faster.

Comment: Normally you'd use intrinsics.  gcc and clang unfortunately can't auto-vectorize loops with a trip-count that's not known before the first iteration, i.e. they can't handle search loops.  ICC can.  Your trick with unconditionally checking 8 elements in the source is good with clang.  For GCC with a small fixed size perhaps consider a uint64_t XOR and then a bithack to detect a zero byte inside an integer, if you can't just use intrinsics.  (Use `memcpy` or an `__attribute__((aligned(1),may_alias))` typedef to do an unaligned aliasing-safe load).